# Applying chain rule to a trace formula in matrix calculus

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

I am trying to differentiate ${\rm tr}(A(X\otimes I_n))$ with respect to $X$. What I have in mind is using chain rule but I am not sure if its correct in matrix calculus

$$
\partial\frac{{\rm tr}(A(X\otimes I_n))}{\partial X}=\partial\frac{{\rm tr}(A(X\otimes I_n))}{\partial (X\otimes I_n)}\frac{\partial X\otimes I_n}{\partial X}
$$

Is this correct? And if so can somebody send me a reference that justifies the step that I take?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove the chain rule for matrix calculus in the exact way you prove it for ordinary calculus, as seen [here](http://kruel.co/math/chainrule.pdf). The only necessary change is to divide by $|H|$ in the definition of the derivative and to multiply by $|H|$ and $|K|$ in the formulae given for $g(X+H)$ and $f(Y+K)$, respectively. So, yes, this will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can find a Kronecker factorization of $A^T$ as
$$A^T = B\otimes C$$
where $B,C$ have the same dimensions as $X,I$ (respectively), then your problem has a very nice solution.

Express your function in terms of the Frobenius product: 
$$ \eqalign{
f &= (X\otimes I):A^T \cr
  &= (X\otimes I):(B\otimes C) \cr
  &= (X:B)\otimes(I:C) \cr
  &= (X:B)\,\,{\rm tr}(C) \cr
} $$
For which the differential is trivial
$$ \eqalign{
df &= dX:B\,\,{\rm tr}(C) \cr
} $$
as is the derivative
$$ \eqalign{
\frac {\partial f} {\partial X} &= B\,\,{\rm tr}(C)\cr
} $$

**Update:**

Even if the matrix can't be factored, it can be decomposed into a finite sum of Kronecker products
$$ \eqalign{
A^T &= \sum_{k=1}^r B_k\otimes C_k \cr
\frac {\partial f} {\partial X} &= \sum_{k=1}^rB_k\,\,{\rm tr}(C_k)\cr
}$$
where $r$ is the rank of the vecpose of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The mapping $X\mapsto tr(A(X\otimes I_n))=:F(X)$ is linear. Hence the derivative is at $X$ in direction $\delta X$ given by
$$
F'(X)\delta X = tr(A(\delta X\otimes I_n)).
$$
You do not need chain rule in this special case. Your reasoning is still correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. In my actual question though it is not linear (what I am differentiating is the expression from the other question that you already answered :) )...